# Why is all data that is passed to a function "explicitly passed"?

Tags: function, methods, argument-passing, implicit

Data is passed to a function "explicitly" whereas a method is "implicitly passed" to the object for which it was called.

Please could you explain the difference between these two ways of passing data? An example in java or c# would help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The language Java and Python are good examples in illustrating this. In Python, the object is passed explicitly whenever a method of a class is defined:

```
class Example(object):

    def method(self, a, b):
        print a, b
        # The variable self can be used to access the current object
```

Here, the object `self` is passed explicitly as the first argument. This means that

```
e = Example()
e.method(3, 4)
```

is effectively the same as calling `method(e, 3, 4)` if `method` were a function.

However, in Java the first argument is not explicitly mentioned:

```
public class Example {
    public void method(int a, int b) {
        System.out.println(a + "  " + b);
        // The variable this can be used to access the current object
    } 
}
```

In Java, it would be:

```
Example e = Example();
e.method(3, 4);
```

The instance `e` is passed to `method` as well but the special variable `this` can be used to access it.

Of course, for functions each argument is passed explicitly because each argument is mentioned in both the function definition and where the function is called. If we define

```
def func(a, b, c):
    print a, b, c
```

then we can call it with `func(1, 2, 3)` which means all arguments are explicitly passed.

Comment: An implicit argument is one that does not need to be mentionned when defining the method? In your Python example, where was the object `self` defined? Could it be any other name? What is the `(object)` after your class `Example` doing? When does one need to access a current object? Many thanks Simeon!

Comment: An implicit argument is one that is not mentioned in the definition of the method (in Java `this` is not mentioned but you can still use it in the method itself). The object `self` is the object `e`: we're calling `e.method(3, 4)` and that means Python calls `method` with the arguments `e` (in the method: `self`), `3` (`a`), and `4` (`b`). The `(object)` means that the class `Example` has `object` as parent class; this has to do with old style and new style classes (no space to explain that here). Lastly, you can access the current object (such as `self` in Python) in the method of a class.

Answer (score 1):

In this context a method can be considered to be a function that has access to the object it's bound to. Any properties of this object can be accessed from the method, even though they didn't appear in the signature of the function. You didn't specify a language, but let me give an example in PHP as it's pretty prevalent and easy to read even if you didn't use it.

Edit: the languages were added after I wrote this; maybe someone can translate this to one of those languages if needed.

```
<?php
/* Explicit passing to a function */
function f($a, b)
{
    return $a + b;
} 

// f(1, 2) == 3

class C
{
    public $a, $b;

    /* $a and $b are not in the parameter list. They're accessed via the special $this variable that points to the current object. */
    public function m() 
    {
        return $this->a + $this->b;
    }

}

$o = new C();
$o->a = 1;
$o->b = 2;
//$o->m() == 3
```